# Function input assistance not working in Mathematica 8?

Tags: autocomplete

I'm sorry if this not allowed here.

On one computer (maybe with a newer version of Mathematica?) the autocomplete/input assistance for functions works perfectly: when I start typing one like ComplexExpand[], it displays a list of functions that start with that word so I can just hit tab. Also, if I make my own functions it learns about them and will autocomplete them.

But on my other computer with Mathematica (Version 8.0.4.0), no list shows up. I've checked in Edit->Preferences->Interface, and there is nothing to turn it on -- strangely though, there is a check box that says "Match case in command completion", which suggests to me that the feature *does* exist in this version.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a V9 functionality. The closest you can get in V8 is the ctrl-K (completion) and cntrl-shift-K (template) functionality.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the ctrl+k deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a V9 functionality. The closest you can get in V8 are the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (complete selection) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (make template) shortcuts to these items in the Edit menu. They also work in V9.